# SQL Query to return one row or field based on 3 conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on a project where I'm trying to have the results of a SQL query emailed out when a certain log message appears in the SQL Server database.

My first goal is to isolate the data I need. The relevant tables are as follows:

```
 System | Time          |   Log  | Index 
  1001  |7/16/2015 7:22 |Fail    |1729943
  1002  |7/17/2015 10:26|Success |1743789
  1002  |7/18/2015 10:26|Success |1743799
  1003  |7/22/2015 6:14 |Timeout |1771793
```

What I'm interested in specifically is the **last** `Time` when system 1002 generates `Success` in `Log`. Seems simple enough but `System` and `Log` are not unique records and the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DB.LogFiles
WHERE System ='1002' and Log ='Success'
```

Returns 2 rows:

```
 System |    Time         |   Log   | Index
 1002   | 7/17/2015 09:43 | Success | 1743789
 1002   | 7/18/2015 10:26 | Success | 1743799
```

I'm in just interested in the **last** `Time` this condition occurred so the last row:

```
1002 | 7/18/2015 10:26 | Success | 1743799
```

That process will repeat everyday so the next day I would see the following records:

```
System |    Time         |   Log   | Index
1002   | 7/17/2015 09:43 | Success | 1743789
1002   | 7/18/2015 10:26 | Success | 1743799
1002   | 7/9/2015  11:42 | Success | 1748752
```

Of which I would like to be notified of again only the new and **last** record

```
1002   | 7/9/2015  11:42   | Success | 1749261
```

The end goal of the project is to have the query scheduled to run every few hours and looking to see if a new ‘Success’  record has been entered. If it has than generate an email. I’m not sure if that portion can be done in SQL however, and I may need to look at something outside of that to accomplish this. Any assistance or insight on at least the SQL portion would be most helpful.

Comment: Are you familiar with TOP 1 and ORDER BY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly that the index is unique and the higher the value the newer the record then you can do something like this.

```
 SELECT a.system, a.time, a.log, a.index
   FROM log_files a
   WHERE a.System ='1002' and a.Log ='Success' 
   AND a.index = (SELECT MAX(z.index) FROM log_files z
                     WHERE z.System = a.System and z.Log = a.Log)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH X AS 
(
    SELECT  [System]
           ,[Time]
           ,[Log]
           ,[Index]
           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [System]
                               ORDER BY CAST([Time] AS DATETIME) DESC) rn
    FROM TableName
)
SELECT [System]
       ,[Time]
       ,[Log]
       ,[Index]
FROM X 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new field (Flag) to your log table with default to FALSE. Whenever you send an email regarding to a record, set the Flag field to TRUE/
every time you want to send the email, just check the record with highest date and only send email if the Flag field is False. If the Flag field is TRUE, just ignore it.